# Is there any managed Property to show searchterms

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server

I want to show "You Searched For: {searchTerms}" at the Top of search page.
I know we can achieve this using javascript, but can we do it using managed property?

Is there any managed property which stores this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A managed property is part of the Search Service and contains a mapping between one or more crawled properties and the defined term that can be used in the search user interface for selecting search parameters or result refiners. Therefore, your question as such does not make sense. You are using the term in a completely wrong context.

So, the answer is: No.

Comment: It Means only javascript is a Option to fetch k's value from url please let me know @teylyn??

Comment: Javascript is reliable and fast. I don't know if it's the ***only*** way, but it can do the job nicely.